How to set the duration of a audioroom with flutter ? (getstream.io)
How can i set when the audioroom end ? the doc is not really clear about that. I might be able to do this with the server-side but i'm not sure.
    Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();  
  final client = StreamVideo(
    'YOUR-API-KEY',
    user: User.regular(userId: 'testing', name: 'Test User'),
    userToken: 'YOUR-USER-TOKEN',
    options: const StreamVideoOptions(
      logPriority: Priority.info,
    ),
  );

  final call = client.makeCall(callType: StreamCallType(), id: '345');
  await call.join();

  runApp(
    StreamVideoGettingStarted(
      call: call,
    ),
  );
}


Currently, there is no way to have a timed session for calls. This is in our backlog, but we can't provide a clear timeline for when this will be out yet.
However, you can manually implement this by ending a call after a certain time. There are multiple ways to do this, e.g., by creating a timer that fires after a given time period, using something like a cron job to clean up sessions regularly, or others.
Hopefully, that was helpful for you. Let me know if that helps you or if you have more questions!
